# CPU warning bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Here is my try to make a script that will sleep:

```
echo "JOB RUN AT $(date)"
echo "======================================="

echo ''
echo 'CPU Warning Limit set to => '$1
echo 'CPU Shutdown Limit set to => '$2
echo ''
echo ''

sensors

echo ''
echo ''
stop=0
while(true)
do
  sleep 1.5
  str=$(sensors | grep "Core $i:")
  newstr=${str:14:2}

  if [ ${newstr} -ge $1 ]
  then
    echo '============================'                             >>/home/xybrek/Desktop/CPUWarning.Log
    echo $(date)                                                    >>/home/xybrek/Desktop/CPUWarning.Log
    echo ''                                                         >>/home/xybrek/Desktop/CPUWarning.Log
    echo ' WARNING: TEMPERATURE CORE' $i 'EXCEEDED' $1 '=>' $newstr >>/home/xybrek/Desktop/CPUWarning.Log
    echo ''                                                         >>/home/xybrek/Desktop/CPUWarning.Log
    echo '============================'                             >>/home/xybrek/Desktop/CPUWarning.Log
  fi

  if [ ${newstr} -ge $2 ]
  then
    echo '============================'
    echo ''
    echo 'CRITICAL: TEMPERATURE CORE' $i 'EXCEEDED' $2 '=>' $newstr
    echo ''
    echo '============================'
    /sbin/pm-suspend
    echo 'Sleeping....'
    exit
  else
    echo ' Temperature Core '$i' OK at =>' $newstr
    echo ''
  fi
done

echo 'Both CPU Cores are within limits'
echo ''
```

When I run the script, it loops every 1.5 seconds but the newStr is not displayed. Its empty. The basic idea of the script is to make the PC 'sleep' when the temperature hits a certain level.

Comment: Where do you set `$i` in `Core $i`?

Comment: Test for str having a value before setting newstr (or test newstr after setting it to the substr).  It's failing since the grep is failing doe to $i not finding a match, thus str is null.

Comment: `bash -x` to troubleshoot

Comment: I managed to fix this script, and now my PC will sleep just before the hardware get into the MAX temp and cut the power off. :-)

Comment: Fine. And the answers did not help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

# PURPOSE: Script to check temperature of CPU cores and report/shutdown if specified temperatures exceeded
#
# AUTHOR: feedback[AT]HaveTheKnowHow[DOT]com

# Expects two arguments:
# 1. Warning temperature
# 2. Critical shutdown temperature
# eg. using ./CPUTempShutdown.sh 30 40
# will warn when temperature of one or more cores hit 30degrees and shutdown when either hits 40degrees.

# NOTES:
# Change the strings ">>/home/xybrek" as required
# Substitute string "myemail@myaddress.com" with your own email address in the string which starts "/usr/sbin/ssmtp myemail@myaddress.com"

# Assumes output from sensors command is as follows:
#
# coretemp-isa-0000
# Adapter: ISA adapter
# Core 0: +35.0 C (high = +78.0 C, crit = +100.0 C) 
#
# coretemp-isa-0001
# Adapter: ISA adapter
# Core 1: +35.0 C (high = +78.0 C, crit = +100.0 C) 
#
# if not then modify the commands str=$(sensors | grep "Core $i:") & newstr=${str:14:2} below accordingly

echo "JOB RUN AT $(date)"
echo "======================================="

echo ''
echo 'CPU Warning Limit set to => '$1
echo 'CPU Shutdown Limit set to => '$2
echo ''
echo ''

sensors

echo ''
echo ''
stop=0
while true;
do
sleep 1.5
for i in 0 1
do
str=$(sensors | grep "Core $i:")
newstr=${str:17:2}

if [[ ${newstr} -ge $1 ]]
then
echo '============================' >>/home/xybrek/Desktop/CPUWarning.Log
echo $(date) >>/home/xybrek/Desktop/CPUWarning.Log
echo '' >>/home/xybrek/Desktop/CPUWarning.Log
echo ' WARNING: TEMPERATURE CORE' $i 'EXCEEDED' $1 '=>' $newstr >>/home/xybrek/Desktop/CPUWarning.Log
echo '' >>/home/xybrek/Desktop/CPUWarning.Log
echo '============================' >>/home/xybrek/Desktop/CPUWarning.Log
fi

if [[ ${newstr} -ge $2 ]]
then
echo '============================'
echo ''
echo 'CRITICAL: TEMPERATURE CORE' $i 'EXCEEDED' $2 '=>' $newstr
echo ''
echo '============================'
sudo pm-suspend
echo 'Sleeping....'
#exit
else
echo ' Temperature Core '$i' OK at =>' $newstr
echo ''
fi
done
done

echo 'Both CPU Cores are within limits'
echo ''
```

Answer (score 0):

`$i` is undefined, as of your code shown.

If `$i` is empty, `$str` will be empty. `$newstr` is a substring of $str, with wrong indices btw.

So `$newstr` will be empty.

Console tests:

```
str@s131-i:~> str=$(sensors | grep "Core 0:")
str@s131-i:~> echo $str
Core 0: +33.0°C (high = +74.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
str@s131-i:~> newstr=${str:14:2}
str@s131-i:~> echo $newstr
+3
str@s131-i:~> str=$(sensors | grep "Core :")
str@s131-i:~> echo $str

str@s131-i:~>
```

Edit one more comment:

This script is not very robust. If the parameters are missing it will put your system to sleep. I would rather use some scripting language for this, if you deploy to several systems use one that does this job without extra libraries or tools. The bash syntax is a bit ...well hm...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Are you shure? Did you test?

Comment: The simple matter is that your original answer was not really an answer, but a comment. If you want to elaborate more, it could be considered a full answer.